# Is there any way to ask the browser to ask permission like being able to prompt for file input via js?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have a keyboard shortcut in an online game, but if the user clicks <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> it should prompt for a savefile. But instead it complains

```
<input> picker was blocked due to lack of user activation.
```

Is there any way I could prompt for this permission (to click without user interaction)?
If it helps, my code creates a hidden `input` tag and clicks it with `.click()` to prompt for savefile.

**EDIT**: I want to open a file

Comment: How are you detecting Ctrl+O keypresses? If you're using a global `keydown` event-listener, then I suggest that you instead use an `<input type="file">` in the DOM with an `accesskey` set, that way the user's keystroke will/should always trigger the picker to open, and then once the user clicks OK/Save then your `change` event-listener would be invoked, thus avoiding any potential issues caused by attempting to manually open a file-picker via JS.

Comment: Are you trying to prompt to open a file or save a file?

Comment: FWIW, to get a Save-File-Picker, use `<a accesskey="s" download="SuggestedFileName.txt" href="blob:yourObjectUrl">`  - and for an Open-File-Picker use `<input type="file" accept="*.txt" accesskey="o" />`.

Comment: You can use file system api to access the file system

Comment: @Dai acceskey is a little hard to standardize, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey).

Comment: Which browser shows this message? `keydown` is an [activation triggering input event](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#activation-triggering-input-event) and thus this message should not be shown from such an event. If needed, you can check if the page is "user-activated" through `navigator.userActivation.isActive`, but obviously, you can't "fake" that activation through user-land scripts since that would defeat the whole purpose of activation gates.